# QT diconnect from wifi

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, wifi

I need to disconnect from current access point. I wrote this piece of code:

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;

QNetworkConfiguration cfg = manager.defaultConfiguration();

// Open session
m_session = new QNetworkSession(cfg);
m_session->open();

m_session->waitForOpened();
```

How can I disconnect from wifi? Or should I use C/C++ (some API) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QProcess and run system commands to connect and disconnect WiFi like below but this is Linux solution:

```
QProcess *system_command = new QProcess();
system_command->start("/bin/bash");
system_command->waitForFinished(500);
system_command->write("nmcli d disconnect wlp3s0\n");
```

Replace **wlp3s0** with your WiFi interface name. You can find your connected WiFi interface name with

```
nmcli c
```

and you can connect your WiFi again with:

```
nmcli d connect wlp3s0
```

For more info check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/461831).